# How to I get this while loop to only prompt the user once at a time

Tags: java

// basically i need to promp the user to enter grades and count the number of A's B's and so on. I cant figure out how to get the loop to loop once per user input. It just spams Enter an exam grade.
Edit thank you all for the help I figured it out!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int numAs = 0;
    int numBs = 0;
    int numCs = 0;
    int numFs = 0;
    int grade = 0;
    while (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)
    System.out.println("Enter an exam grade");
    grade = input.nextInt();
    if (grade >= 90) {numAs++;
    }else if (grade >=80 && grade<= 89 ) {numBs++;
    }else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {numCs++;
    }else if (grade <= 69) {numFs++;
    }else if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) {System.out.println("Error invalid grade entered.");
    }
    }
```

}

Comment: I have removed the javascript tag. Note Java and JavaScript are entirely different programming languages.

Comment: `while (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100)` You are missing a `{` here.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing your curly braces after your while statement. If there are no curly braces specified, the while loop only includes the following statement, not the whole block.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int numAs = 0;
    int numBs = 0;
    int numCs = 0;
    int numFs = 0;
    int grade = 0;
    while (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100){
    System.out.println("Enter an exam grade");
    grade = input.nextInt();
    if (grade >= 90) {numAs++;
    }
    else if (grade >=80 && grade<= 89 ) {numBs++;
    }
    else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {numCs++;
    }
    else if (grade <= 69) {numFs++;
    }
    else if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) {System.out.println("Error invalid grade entered.");
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you formatted the code correctly, you would see that your While loop doesn't have curly braces, thus it includes only the following line in it.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int numAs = 0;
int numBs = 0;
int numCs = 0;
int numFs = 0;
int grade = 0;
while (grade >= 0 && grade <= 100) 
    System.out.println("Enter an exam grade");
    //WHILE ENDS HERE
grade = input.nextInt();
if (grade >= 90) {
    numAs++;
} else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
    numBs++;
} else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
    numCs++;
} else if (grade <= 69) {
    numFs++;
} else if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) {
    System.out.println("Error invalid grade entered.");
}
```

And even if You add the missing `{`, it doesn't solve multiple issues - what happens on an incorrect input; and how do you stop the loop correctly. So all things considered, this might be a bit better:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int numAs = 0, numBs = 0, numCs = 0, numFs = 0;
int grade = 0;
String in = "";
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter an exam grade or Q to exit");
    //WHILE ENDS HERE
    in = input.nextLine();
    if ("Q".equals(in)) {
        System.out.println("That's it!");
        break;
    }
    try {
        grade = Integer.parseInt(in); //get caught if not a num
        if (grade < 0 || grade > 100) { //gets caught if bad num
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error invalid grade entered.");
    }
    if (grade >= 90)
        numAs++;
    else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89)
        numBs++;
    else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79)
        numCs++;
    else if (grade <= 69)
        numFs++;
    System.out.println("Saved.");
}
//Continue after breaking the loop
```